# How to access variables in more global functions within a nested function? (Python)

Tags: python, function, variables, scope, nested

I am running a function within another function. However, the more nested function is unable to access the variables in the main, more global function. When I attempt to run my code I get "x is not defined" error. I would think that since x is a more global variable higher in scope, it should be accessible.

```
def func_master():
    x = 'hello world'
    test_sub()


def test_sub():
    print(x)

func_master()
```

I want it to print out 'hello world'.

Comment: Python had lexical, not dynamic, variable scope, so what you want must be achieved by other means such as explicit passing of arguments, or using globals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions are not "nested," which means that one is *defined* inside the other. You instead are *calling* one function from inside another, but the functions are *defined* separately, neither inside the other.

Python's scope rules are based on how the functions are *defined*. So when `func_master` calls `test_sub`, the name `x` that was defined in `func_master` is not accessible to `test_sub`.

The best (but not only) way to make `x` usable in `test_sub` is to pass it as a parameter. Modify the call in `func_master` to pass `x` and modify the definition of `test_sub` to receive it. It is good programming practice for one routine to pass all the needed information as parameters--avoid using global variables etc. unless they are absolutely needed.

```
def func_master():
    x = 'hello world'
    test_sub(x)


def test_sub(x):
    print(x)

func_master()
```

Comment: Thanks! I am glad there is a way to do this without using global variables. I was imagining a case with multiple functions within functions within functions, and using only globals seemed like a headache.

Also, thanks for helping me with my terminology. I am very new, and still trying to get the words right.